# Functional and non functional requirements relating to web API

Tags: requirements, system-requirements

is the development of a RESTful API in JSON that will later be consumed by a web frontend a "Functional" or "non functional" requirement?

Answer (score 2):

It is neither. "The development of a RESTful API in JSON" is not a requirement, but just describes the process of implementing one or more underlying requirements.

**But you probably refer to a functional requirement.**

You should always seek to split requirements, which describe a function or quality that the future system shall have, from their technical implementation.

Such a functional requirement could be:

> (identifier 1) The system under development must offer the following
>   information to external systems via an interface: (table of required
>   information)

Then you can break that down further into more detailed functional requirements, one of which can be:

> (identifier 2) The system under development must offer its
>   information specified in (*reference to identifier 1*) to external
>   systems in the JSON format via an interface that is accessible for
>   REST clients, in order to feed *external system XYZ*.

Nonfunctional requirements, in contrast, tell more details about the API qualities. Such as:

- Performance
- Security
- Reliability
- Usability
- Maintainability
- Portability

Because these things are hard to measure, you can add more functional requirements which specify expected behavior in more detail (such as max. response times).

Source:

https://ireb.org/en/downloads/#syllabus-foundation-level